# Query to get latest datetime for 2 columns individually

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

```
create table Orders
(
city varchar(5)
,orderid int
,OrderedDateTime datetime
,ThresholdDatetime datetime
)

insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-24 12:20:56.560','2017-08-24 20:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-24 13:20:45.560','2017-08-24 22:20:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-24 16:20:45.560','2017-08-24 20:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-24 17:20:23.560','2017-08-24 22:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-23 12:20:23.560','2017-08-23 14:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-23 13:20:23.560','2017-08-23 21:20:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-23 16:20:23.560','2017-08-23 20:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-23 18:20:23.560','2017-08-23 20:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-22 12:20:23.560','2017-08-22 14:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-22 13:20:23.560','2017-08-22 21:20:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-22 16:20:23.560','2017-08-22 20:00:23.000')
insert into Orders values ('Texas',23,'2017-08-22 19:20:23.560','2017-08-22 20:00:23.000')
```

[image: Given data as below[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF46S.jpg)

The requirement is to get latest datetime from the 'orderedDateTime' column and latest datetime from 'ThresholdDateTime' column  which should return a record for each day as mentioned in the output image.
I already have a solution for this, but seeking better answers than mine , as i think my query is having performance issues

```
select city,orderid, max(OrderedDateTime) as MaxOrderedDateTime ,max(ThresholdDatetime) as MaxThresholdTime
,day(ThresholdDatetime) as [UniqueDay]
from dbo.Orders 
where OrderedDateTime<=ThresholdDatetime
and convert(date,OrderedDateTime)=convert(date,ThresholdDatetime)
group by city,orderid,day(ThresholdDatetime)
```

Comment: Why do you think you query is having performance issues? Your query seems to be correct to return the data you are looking for.

Comment: Are you getting any error of any kind?

Comment: This query is going to return wrong output if you have data for more than 1 month as the output of day(ThresholdDatetime)  will be repeated after 30 days. So you need to and Month(ThresholdDatetime) and year(ThresholdDatetime) in group by clause based on amount of data you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try coding like this:

```
SELECT 
    o.city,
    o.orderid,
    MaxOrderedDateTime = MAX(o.OrderedDateTime),
    MaxThresholdTime = MAX(o.ThresholdDatetime)
FROM
    #Orders o
GROUP BY
    o.city,
    o.orderid,
    CAST(o.OrderedDateTime AS DATE);
```